# I missed the "Chunks of spacecraft have impacted nearby" message -- where did it happen?

Tags: rimworld

I did not click it in time.
The message disappeared and now I don't know where it happened.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Go to History panel
2. Go to Messages tab
3. Turn on the Show messages
4. **Right click** on the message

Also right click is useful to click through the list of Wildlife.